# Asyncronous service in while loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, alfresco

I'm creating an angular component which has to get a taskId using an asynchronous [service](https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/process-services/services/tasklist.service/) and pass it as another [component's](https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/process-services/components/task-details.component/) property to display the correct task.
The problem is that the task itself is created shortly (up to 3-5 seconds) after the initiation of my component. 

The code below includes the lastTaskId variable (storing the taskId, initially empty ""), getTaskId function (contains the getTasks [service](https://www.alfresco.com/abn/adf/docs/process-services/services/tasklist.service/), which in turn uses taskQuery to pass search parameters) and the ngOnInit() with a while loop inside.

My idea was to use the while loop running untill the getTaskId function changes the lastTaskId variable to something. Didn't work because it seems the getTaskId function is asynchronous and is executed after the loop, which is never.

Thanks for any help!

```
lastTaskId: string = "";

ngOnInit() {
  while (this.lastTaskId == "") {
    this.getTaskId();
  }
}

getTaskId() {
  const taskQuery: TaskQueryRequestRepresentationModel = {
    processInstanceId: 1,
    state: 'open',
  };

this.tasklistService.getTasks(taskQuery).subscribe((taskListModel: TaskListModel) => {
  this.lastTaskId = taskListModel.data[0].id;
}, error => {
  console.log('Error: ', error);
});}
```

Comment: "My idea was to use the while loop running untill the getTaskId function changes the lastTaskId variable to something" this doesn't explain why you attempted to use a while loop. A loop is used when you want to repeat the same instruction several times

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to prevent showing the child component until `lastTaskId` has a value? Or are you waiting for the server to return a value?

Comment: I want to show the task as soon as it is created. The point of the while loop was to wait until it's created.

Comment: @dzider But *why* do you want to wait? What's depending on it?

Comment: The whole thing is about starting a process and going through several tasks immediately. User starts a process in the first dialog. This dialog closes and the second dialog containing the task of this process opens at once. I have to wait for the task because starting a process and the creation of the task don't happen simultaneously. The task is created shortly after the second dialog is opened. The delay is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to implement this and tell me what will happen

```
lastTaskId: string = "";
async ngOnInit() {
    await this.getTaskId();

}

async getTaskId() {
    const taskQuery: TaskQueryRequestRepresentationModel = {
        processInstanceId: 1,
        state: 'open',
    };
    const taskListModel = await this.tasklistService.getTasks(taskQuery).toPromise();
    this.lastTaskId = taskListModel.data[0].id;
}
```

Comment: Why is converting an observable to a promise going to solve anything? This is functionally the same as the question, just without the pointless loop.

Comment: so you can wait to get response and you can *ngIf directive in your template like *ngIf="lastTaskId" and this way is clear than make loop

Comment: core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
I think it's cause the task isn't created yet. that's why I was thinking about the while loop in the first place

Comment: Could you log taskListModel to see the response ?

Comment: @dzider Have you checked that the object structure is what you are expecting

Comment: @AhmedKesha I added console.log(taskListModel) to the getTaskId() method but all I got was the error mentioned above: 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: @KurtHamilton I'm sure there exists the id property to this object. Everything worked when I put the getTaskId() into the ngDoCheck. It was just very slow.

Comment: @dzider Can you recreate in a stackblitz. Your major problem at the moment is that you are going to create a ton of subscriptions.

Comment: I am with @KurtHamilton you have to recreate stackblitz

Comment: I can't. I'm creating an application using Alfresco Development Framework which uses my local Alfresco.